# get images attachments from Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageInstance

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

```
$client = new Client($twilio->sid, $twilio->token);
$response = $client->messages->read();
foreach($response as $text_message) {
    dd($text_message);
```

Getting a text message this way gives me some uri's, but going to the uri's does not give me a url.

When you receive a text message from a callback url registered in the twilio console, it includes a POST/GET with the parameter $input['MediaUrl' . $i], where the attachment from a text message is hosted.

How can I get that same MediaUrl from a Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageInstance?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can read about [accessing media from messages in the docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/media-resource). If you make a request to the media's URL without an extension, you should get the media with it's original content type. If you add `.json` or `.xml` to the URL then you will get the data about the media in the format you requested.