# Can't get mediaUrl from messages list Twilio programmable SMS

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am using programmable SMS to send messages. I have a history page in my app

When history page loads, I am sending a request to my Node.js backend to trigger this twilio function

```
 await subClient.messages.list({limit: 5})
                .then(messages => messages.forEach(m => m.direction === "outbound-api" ? messageArr.push(m) : ""));
     
                    console.log("messageARr", messageArr)
```

This is what the result looks like

```
  },
  {
    body: 'This is a scheduled message with an image url',
    numSegments: '1',
    direction: 'outbound-api',
    from: '+17208',
    to: '+17209',
    dateUpdated: 2022-07-11T03:07:46.000Z,
    price: '-0.02000',
    errorMessage: null,
    uri: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC3f5822babc/Messages/MM882d0415d9e1.json',
    accountSid: 'AC3f5822ba',
    numMedia: '1',
    status: 'delivered',
    messagingServiceSid: null,
    sid: 'MM882d0415d9e94f',
    dateSent: 2022-07-11T03:07:33.000Z,
    dateCreated: 2022-07-11T03:07:32.000Z,
    errorCode: null,
    priceUnit: 'USD',
    apiVersion: '2010-04-01',
    subresourceUris: {
      media: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC3f5822bab/Messages/MM882d0415d9e94/Media.json',
      feedback: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC3f5822babc/Messages/MM882d0415d9e91/Feedback.json'
    }
  },
```

I put this data into a table, and when a user clicks on a message, I want to retrieve the media associated with this message and show them an  with a preview of the media.

According to the docs I need to send a request to the subresourceUri.media from the message object.

So I send a request to my node server with the above objects subresourceUri.media uri and run this get request below

```
 const mediaInfo = await axios({ 
                    url:`https://api.twilio.com${req.body.subresourceUri.media}`,
                    method:"GET",
                    auth: { username: subActServiceSid, password: subActAuthToken }
                    }).then(res => { return res.data})
                   console.log("mediaSid", mediaInfo)
```

This returns a JSON object like below

```
mediaInfo {
  first_page_uri: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC3f5822babc3/Messages/MMdf439bd7eaf1/Media.json?PageSize=50&Page=0',
  end: 0,
  media_list: [
    {
      sid: 'ME198b5b06be57d98',
      account_sid: 'AC3f5822babc',
      parent_sid: 'MMdf439bd7e',
      content_type: 'image/jpeg',
      date_created: 'Mon, 11 Jul 2022 03:24:55 +0000',
      date_updated: 'Mon, 11 Jul 2022 03:24:55 +0000',
      uri: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC3f5822babc3/Messages/MMdf439bd7e1/Media/ME198b5b06be57d.json'
    }
  ],
  previous_page_uri: null,
  uri: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC3f5822babc3/Messages/MMdf439bd71/Media.json?PageSize=50&Page=0',
  page_size: 50,
  start: 0,
  next_page_uri: null,
  page: 0
}
```

Now I am expecting to query this mediaInfo.media_list[0].uri and get back the actual media file or something to send back to front end to show an image. Either make a blob and get request it for preview.

I am stuck in a loop when I run a get request on this media_list[0].uri I just get back the JSON object like this

```
uri Result {
  sid: 'ME198b5b06be57d',
  account_sid: 'AC3f5822babc37',
  parent_sid: 'MMdf439bd7ea',
  content_type: 'image/jpeg',
  date_created: 'Mon, 11 Jul 2022 03:24:55 +0000',
  date_updated: 'Mon, 11 Jul 2022 03:24:55 +0000',
  uri: '/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC3f5822babc3/Messages/MMdf439b1/Media/ME198b5b06be57d98.json'
}
```

How do I get the the mediaUrl associated with the SMS or just the image File itself?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at this link,

I am doing it correctly just need to query WITHOUT the .json lol.....

[get images attachments from Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70155238/get-images-attachments-from-twilio-rest-api-v2010-account-messageinstance)